# Why XmlSerializer.Serialize() looks for referenced assembly with specific version?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, dll

We have a project with following folder deployment hierarchy:

- [Folder] Main

  - Main.exe
- [Folder] Tasks

  - TaskA.dll
  - Model.dll

`Main.exe` looks like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var assemblyPath = args[0];
    var className = args[1];

    IBatch batch = Assembly
        .LoadFrom(assemblyPath)
        .CreateInstance(className) as IBatch;

    batch.Execute();
}
```

In `TaskA.dll`, we'd like to serialize an instance of following class into XML:
(`class Task` is defined in `TaskA.dll` and `enum Model.Kind` is defined in `Model.dll`

```
public class Task
{
    public Source? Source { get; set; }
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public Model.Kind? Kind { get; set; }
}
```

The serialization code looks like this:

```
var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Task));

StringBuilder xmlStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

using (var writer = new StringWriter(xmlStringBuilder))
{
    xmlSerializer.Serialize(writer, task);
}

var result = xmlStringBuilder.ToString();
```

The execution works fine at first. But if we replaced `Model.dll` from `1.0.1708.401` to `1.0.1709.101`, it will throw following exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error generating the XML document. --->
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 
Could not load file or assembly 'Model, Version=1.0.1708.401, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies.
The system cannot find the file specified. 
at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriterTask.Write3_Task(String n, String ns, Task o, Boolean isNullable, Boolean needType) 
at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriterTask.Write4_Task(Object o) 
--- End of inner exception stack trace --- 
at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(XmlWriter xmlWriter, Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces, String encodingStyle, String id) 
at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(TextWriter textWriter, Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces)
```

Although it can be fixed by registering `AssemblyResolve` event handler to return non-specific version assembly like this:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (sender, arg) =>
{
    var path = Path.Combine(
        Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location),
        $"{new AssemblyName(arg.Name).Name}.dll");

    return Assembly.LoadFrom(path);
};
```

We are still very curious why `XmlSerializer.Serialize()` looks for specific version at the first place?

Comment: How does xml looks like? My guess `1.0.1708.401` version is specified there explicitly.

Comment: @Sinatr it contains no version information and just looks like a typical xml you would expect from xml serialization